# Mean conditional on sum

Tags: independence, conditional-expectation, convolution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables. I am interested in how $\mathrm{E}[X | X + Y = z]$ changes as $z$ changes.

Intuitively, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the conditional mean should be increasing in $z$. If I am told the sum takes a high value, I would expect that its component would also be high. If $X$ and $Y$ are positively correlated, the same intuition would hold. If they are negatively correlated in a certain manner, then the conditional mean may not be increasing in $z$.

Ideally, I would like to characterize the conditions under which this conditional mean is non-decreasing in $z$. If it helps, I am willing to assume $X$ and $Y$ are absolutely continuous and have non-negative support.

I am struggling even just to show the conditional mean is increasing when $X$ and $Y$ are independent. For specific cases, such as when both are independent Gaussian, I can show that the conditional mean is in fact increasing in $z$, linearly in this particular case. But I am unable to produce proof for the general case.

I can express the conditional mean, using independence, as $\mathrm{E}[X | X + Y = z] = \frac{\int x f_X(x) f_Y(z-x) dx}{\int f_X(x) f_Y(z-x) dx}$, where $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are pdfs of $X$ and $Y$, respectively (invoking absolute continuity for their existences). This expression doesn't seem to help me much, however.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a bivariate Normal model as a testing example.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. As discussed in the post, I have shown that if X and Y are independent Normal, then E[X | X+Y = z] = az, where a>0. Based on numerical results, I also think the result holds even when (X, Y) follows bivariate Normal with non-zero covariance, with the possibility of a < 0 when the correlation is sufficiently negative. Still, I struggle to generalize from this example.